# Android ActionbarSherlock show menu button at top

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to implement ActionBarSherlock in my application and I need to show the menu at the top of my application, integrated in action bar. The problem is that it's not working properly. I am using it like this :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Refresh")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    menu.add("Settings")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_settings)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return true;
}
```

So the thing which I want to achieve is to show at the right side of my action bar a refresh icon and a menu icon, which should open the default menus when clicked. I checked `ForcedOverflowItem` example in ActionbarSherlock Demos, but it's not working as I want. I need to look the same as in Android 2.+ and in Android 4.+.

Any advices /  helps / suggestions how can I get this to work?

Comment: you cant show the overflow menu on ICS+, ABS lib is updated to v4.2.0. removed ForceOverflow

Comment: So you want an `Overflow` menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I read in  ActionbarSherlock's documentation you cannot force the menu icon to appear in Android 4.+. When the device has a menu button the menu icon does not appear. I guess the guy who wrote ActionbarSherlock knows the subject matter well ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You can do an xml file line this. 
I saw this in some other post but I cannot track it rigth now.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/remove"
                android:showAsAction="withText|never"
                android:title="@string/remove">
            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Then just inflate it like a normal menu.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overlow, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why the down votes? I am using this method. If something is wrong please reply so I can justify or learn something new and change my code.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the dorjeduck's answer. If you want have same experience on all devices you have to add custom menu with his submenus. Here this the code sumple:

```
SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu("More");
sub.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark);
sub.add(0, MENU_SETTINGS, 0, "Settings");
```

Comment: yes but it's not working with `tabactivity`, because my application is using tabs, not like in android 4.0 api - fragments.

Comment: I don't understand, in which connection is your question and tabactivity ? but you can change your tabs to actionbar's tabs