# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: sHasPermanentMenuKey

Tags: java, android

The hack that developers have used in the past to allow a Hardware and Software menu button in the `ActionBar`, is:

```
try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }

} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Results in: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: sHasPermanentMenuKey`

So the hack doesn't work anymore, an alternative?
Edit: So the hack never worked for < Android 4.2, an alternative (without creating the button yourself)?

(I don't want to start another discussion as in [How To Control use of OverFlow Menu in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871850/how-to-control-use-of-overflow-menu-in-ics) about pros and cons of this approach)

Comment: What version of Android do you use? In 4.4.2 it is [there](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java/#230) but on earlier versions it isn't.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel Android 2.3.5

Comment: As expected, it is [not available](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java/) in 2.3.5. The first occurrence I see is in 4.0.1_r1.

Comment: Well, for 2.3.5, there is no action bar, except via a library. Hence, you will need to find a recipe for the particular library you are using.

Comment: @CommonsWare I use the class from the support library android.support.v7.app.ActionBar, I could create another menu, but this seems cumbersome

Comment: FYI, I got this bug recently: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: sHasPermanentMenuKey : at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:596). It happened with 6 different users, all using version 4.4.2.